# Cancel File Upload: Multer, MongoDB

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload, multer, multer-gridfs-storage

I can't seem to find any **up-to-date answers** on how to cancel a file upload using Mongo, NodeJS & Angular. I've only come across some tuttorials on how to delete a file but that is **NOT** what I am looking for. I want to be able to cancel the file uploading process by clicking a button on my front-end.

**I am storing my files directly to the MongoDB in chuncks using the Mongoose, Multer & GridFSBucket packages**. I know that I can stop a file's uploading process on the front-end by **unsubscribing** from the subsribable responsible for the upload in the front-end, but the upload process keeps going in the back-end when I unsubscribe** (Yes, I have double and triple checked. All the chunks keep getting uploaded untill the file is fully uploaded.)

Here is my **Angular code**:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Upload the file.
    this.sub = this.mediaService.addFile(this.formData).subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      console.log(event);
      switch (event.type) {
        case HttpEventType.Sent:
          console.log('Request has been made!');
          break;
        case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
          console.log('Response header has been received!');
          break;
        case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
          // Update the upload progress!
          this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
          console.log(`Uploading! ${this.progress}%`);
          break;
        case HttpEventType.Response:
          console.log('File successfully uploaded!', event.body);
          this.body = 'File successfully uploaded!';
      }
    },
    err => {
      this.progress = 0;
      this.body = 'Could not upload the file!';
    });
  }


  **CANCEL THE UPLOAD**
  cancel() {
    // Unsubscribe from the upload method.
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Here is my **NodeJS (Express) code**:

```
...

// Configure a strategy for uploading files.
const multerUpload = multer({ 
    // Set the storage strategy.
    storage: storage,
    // Set the size limits for uploading a file to 120MB.
    limits: 1024 * 1024 * 120,
    // Set the file filter.
    fileFilter: fileFilter
}); 

// Add new media to the database.
router.post('/add', [multerUpload.single('file')], async (req, res)=>{
    return res.status(200).send();
});
```

What is the right way to cancel the upload **without leaving any chuncks** in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have been trying to get to the bottom of this for 2 days now and I believe I have found a satisfying solution:

**First**, in order to cancel the file upload and delete any chunks that have already been uploaded to MongoDB, you need to **adjust the fileFilter in your multer configuration** in such a way to detect if the request has been aborted and the upload stream has ended. Then reject the upload by throwing an error using fileFilter's callback:

```
// Adjust what files can be stored.
const fileFilter = function(req, file, callback){
    console.log('The file being filtered', file)

    req.on('aborted', () => {
        file.stream.on('end', () => {
            console.log('Cancel the upload')
            callback(new Error('Cancel.'), false);
        });
        file.stream.emit('end');
    })
}
```

**NOTE THAT**: When canceling a file upload, you must **wait for the changes to show up on your database**. The chunks that have already been sent to the database will first have to be uploaded before the canceled file gets deleted from the database. This might take a while depending on your internet speed and the bytes that were sent before canceling the upload.

**Finally**, you might want to set up a route in your backend to **delete any chunks from files that have not been fully uploaded to the database** (due to some error that might have occured during the upload). In order to do that you'll need to fetch the all file IDs from your .chunks collection ([by following the method specified on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64832155/mongoose-cannot-fetch-file-documents-from-chunk-collection-without-the-data-fi)) and **separate the IDs of the files whose chunks have been partially uploaded to the database from the IDs of the files that have been fully uploaded**. Then you'll need to call GridFSBucket's delete() method on those IDs in order to get rid of the redundant chunks. This step is purely optional and for database maintenance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try using try catch way.

There can be two ways it can be done.

1. By calling an api which takes the file that is currently been uploaded as it's parameter and then on backend do the steps of delete and clear the chunks that are present on the server
2. By handling in exception.
   By sending a file size as a validation where if the backend api has received the file totally of it size then it is to be kept OR if the size of the received file is less that is due to cancellation of upload bin between then do the clearance steps where you just take the id and mongoose db of the files chuck and clear it.

Comment: I cannot delete a file that hasn't been fully uploaded yet since MongoDB seperates media file data into 2 collections: media.chunks & media.files. In order to delete the file's chunks which are stored in the media.chunks collection, you need the file's metadata which are stored in the media.files collection. The metadata do NOT appear in the media.files collection if the file hasn't been fully uploaded.

Is there a way to check if the file has been fully uploaded while it's being uploaded? Or some way to throw an exception if the expected file size hasn't been reached?